# Obtengo un Null Pointer al usar Glide con Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, glide

A las buenas, a ver, estoy tratando de cargar una imagen con Glide en Android Studio, hasta ahora me había funcionado bien ya que estaba haciendolo con Activity pero ahora he cambiado a usar Fragments y no se si es casualidad o ese ha sido el motivo, os voy a dejar por aquí el contenido:

El contenido del Fragment que contiene la orden de Glide:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private var imageView: ImageView? = null

companion object {
    fun newInstance(): HomeFragment = HomeFragment()
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    imageView?.let{
        GlideApp.with(this).load(R.drawable.isaac_image).into(ivMyPhoto)
    }


}

}
```

Aquí os dejo el modulo que he leido que tenía que crear para usar Glide con Kotlin, pero ya estoy un poco liado y no se si tengo que usarlo:

```
package com.isaac.lookatme

import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule

@GlideModule
class MyGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {

}
```

Y ahora el contenido del XML del Fragment, que es donde tengo el XML donde quiero cargar la imagen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ContactFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlMyPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:paddingStart="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivMyPhoto"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivMyPhoto"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAnswerTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/answer_title"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPurple"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMyName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvAnswerTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/my_name"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#8D8D8D"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMyJob"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvMyName"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="ser"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/my_job"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#535353"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMyDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlMyPhoto"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:justificationMode="inter_word"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
        android:text="@string/my_value"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

El caso es que como tengo ahora mismo el código no me está dando el NPE, pero de todas formas no me está cargando la imagen. A ver si me podéis echar una mano :)

Comment: Hola Issac, Acostumbra agregar el LogCat para saber especificamente donde ocurren los errores.

Comment: Te recomiendo usar la libreria coil-kt para la carga de graficos https://github.com/coil-kt/coil

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer no existe la referencia del `ImageView` con id `ivMyPhoto` en el `layout fragment_home.xml` por esta razón obtienes `NullPointerException`.

Asegura que este elemento se encuentre en `layout fragment_home.xml` .

Por cierto usa la dependencia indicada en la [documentación](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) :

```
...
...
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
  ...
  ...
}
```

y carga la imagen de esta forma dentro del ImagenView `ivMyPhoto`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

//    imageView?.let{
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.isaac_image).into(ivMyPhoto)
//   }


}
```

Comment: Parece que no lo estaba poniendo donde era. Los Activities y los Fragment tienen ciclos de vida diferentes. Yo estaba colocando esto en el onCreate del Fragment. Mi solución ha sido añadirlo en el método onCreateActivity y ahí si me lo ha reconocido todo sin problemas. No se si tiene mucho sentido, pero si funciona creo que si jaja